# How to get the screen resolution of Samsung 7 inch tablet?

Tags: android

*Hi guys,
        I am developing an application for both tablets as well as mobile,Till now every thing is fine to me. Here is my problem,I can't get the height and width of Samsung Galaxy Tab?*

- I want what is configuration for 7 inch tablet i have declared as 
  config.orientation == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE. It is not working for me.
- if else how i need to declare this.
- here i have declared i n the layout as layout-large it's working for me, but i am having both design for landscape and protrait.

Comment: which 7'' tablet you have...there's 7'' tablets which can be SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE

Comment: i don't  the model number exactly  i am using the emulator of Samsung galaxy tab..

Comment: do you want to check orientation?

Comment: s orentation and  what is the screen resolution..... like SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE or SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4570/discussion-between-gujjula-nikhilreddy-and-evilone)

Comment: config.orientation == Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE. This is wrong. Screen size is not the same as orienation.

Comment: then how we can declare can u help me plz..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the size classification — ”small”, “normal”, “large”, “xlarge” — use the Configuration class:

```
Configuration config = getResources().getConfiguration();
int size = config.screenLayout & config.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK;

if (size == config.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_SMALL)
{
    // use special layout for small screens
}
```

If you need check for a orientation then you can use:

```
public int getScreenOrientation()
{
    Display getOrient = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    int orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED;

    if(getOrient.getWidth() == getOrient.getHeight()) {
        orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_SQUARE;
    } else { 
        if(getOrient.getWidth() < getOrient.getHeight()){
            orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        } else { 
             orientation = Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
        }
    }

    return orientation;
}
```

I don't really get it, why you need check for a screen size, because if you add your layouts in different layout folders, then Android automatically selects most suitable depending on screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
String strScreenSize = "The Android Screen is: "
    + dm.widthPixels
    + " x "
    + dm.heightPixels;
```

Comment: Try SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_NORMAL instead of SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_LARGE

Answer (score 0):

There are several websites that fetch this kind of info, without you having to write scripts.
e.g. http://www.screenresolution.org/